# Vaadin: How do I make a Component selectable with a RadioButton?

Tags: java, web, vaadin

I have a use case where the user needs to select items with checkboxes and then has a choice of two radio buttons. Now the plan was to use the radio buttons to select a component. One RadioButton would select a ComboBox, the other a TextField. However, I can't make this work nor did I find any info when googling.

Am I missing something? If I use setItems(), I get the object reference, not the object itself.

Thank you!

Edit - Code which I tried:

```
RadioButtonGroup<Component> rbg = new RadioButtonGroup();
TextField tf = new TextField("foo");
ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox();
rbg.setItems(tf, cb);
```

And

```
RadioButtonGroup<Component> rbg = new RadioButtonGroup();
TextField tf = new TextField("foo");
ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox();
rbg.add(tf, cb);
```

I tried to play around with different types and methods, but to no luck.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I understand that. There isn't really any code to post that might be relevant to this though. The only thing I tried was using radioButtonGroup.setItems(), passing the textField and ComboBox, but that resulted in the object references being displayed rather than the actual UI Component.

Comment: Post the code where you're calling setItems, at least, it sounds like you're using it wrong. More code is better.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure from your description, but it sounds like you're trying to use components instead of text labels for the items in a radio button group? If that is indeed the case, then you need to use a `ComponentRenderer`. https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-radio-button/java-examples/presentation

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<Component>` as the generic type parameter for a field. You'll need something like this:

```java
        RadioButtonGroup<String> radioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
        radioButtonGroup.setItems("foo", "bar");
        radioButtonGroup.setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer<>(item -> {
            if ("foo".equals(item)) {
                TextField textField = new TextField();
                return textField;
            } else {
                ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
                comboBox.setItems("baz", "quux");
                return comboBox;
            }
        }));
        radioButtonGroup.setValue("foo");
        add(radioButtonGroup);
```